# Nested looping with map from purrr package in R

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse, purrr

In my `map()` call below, I want to first loop over `time` from 0 to 7 (`0:7`), keeping `ses = 0`. Then, again loop over `time` from 0 to 7 (`0:7`), keeping `ses = 1`.

I was wondering how to fix my loop below?

```
library(purrr)
library(emmeans)

dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/dat2.csv')

fit <- lm(math ~ time*ses + I(time^2)*ses, data = dat)


map(0:1, ~map_df(0:7, 
    ~data.frame(summary(emtrends(fit, ~ses, var= "time", max.degree= 2,at =list(ses=.,time=.))))[1,]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an anonymous function call here to avoid the confusion and be clear of what is what.

```
map(0:1, function(x) 
  map_df(0:7,function(y)
               data.frame(summary(emtrends(fit, 
          ~ses, var= "time", max.degree= 2,at =list(ses=x,time=y))))[1,]))

#[[1]]
#  ses degree time.trend         SE   df    lower.CL  upper.CL
#1   0 linear 0.34156633 0.06084479 1594  0.22222212 0.4609105
#2   0 linear 0.29736820 0.04502015 1594  0.20906326 0.3856731
#3   0 linear 0.25317006 0.03015484 1594  0.19402275 0.3123174
#4   0 linear 0.20897192 0.01869728 1594  0.17229808 0.2456458
#5   0 linear 0.16477378 0.01864500 1594  0.12820248 0.2013451
#6   0 linear 0.12057564 0.03005757 1594  0.06161911 0.1795322
#7   0 linear 0.07637750 0.04491162 1594 -0.01171454 0.1644695
#8   0 linear 0.03217936 0.06073239 1594 -0.08694438 0.1513031

#[[2]]
#  ses degree time.trend         SE   df    lower.CL  upper.CL
#1   1 linear 0.43528003 0.08297255 1594  0.27253325 0.5980268
#2   1 linear 0.38631190 0.06139288 1594  0.26589262 0.5067312
#3   1 linear 0.33734376 0.04112141 1594  0.25668603 0.4180015
#4   1 linear 0.28837563 0.02549702 1594  0.23836441 0.3383868
#5   1 linear 0.23940750 0.02542573 1594  0.18953612 0.2892789
#6   1 linear 0.19043936 0.04098878 1594  0.11004179 0.2708369
#7   1 linear 0.14147123 0.06124487 1594  0.02134227 0.2616002
#8   1 linear 0.09250309 0.08281927 1594 -0.06994303 0.2549492
```